# Deploy changes to child project of eclipse multi-module maven project to tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

When working with eclipse (Neon) single module maven projects I can easily use use the Java builder (faster than the eclipse maven builder) to keep my project automatically compiled and I can immediately synchronise my code changes to a tomcat server which I have added to eclipse. Sometimes I will have to modify my deployment assembly settings to make sure i'm deploying the resources that I intend, but that's all good.

When I add extra modules into the mix in multi-module maven projects, i run into problems with eclipse. Each module is a separate project in eclipse which is fine and dandy, but when i make a change to a "child" module in eclipse, then synchronise the "parent" module/project with tomcat in eclipse as usual, the changes to the "child" project are not copied across to tomcat. The project seems correctly setup in eclipse with the child modules added as deployment artifacts in the deployment assembly settings, and the child module jars also correctly identified as java dependencies.

What I have to do is complete a full maven build outside the IDE, then refresh eclipse and do a synchronise to tomcat and then the changes are copied across successfully. I would really like to avoid this cumbersome workflow as it is so awkward and slow compared to my single project/module workflow..

Here is my tomcat configuration:
[Tomcat Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymnIl.png)

Comment: Give more details, please: What kind of changes do you make to your child modules? And also: Is checked the "server modules without publishing" server option?

Comment: > What kind of changes do you make to your child modules? (java code changes within methods etc.) > Is checked the "server modules without publishing" server option (no this is not checked, i will update my question with a snap of my server configuration)